# Overlapping Component with Listener Android

Tags: android, onclicklistener, overlapping

I have a problem with listeners when overlapping components in Android View.
In my case I show a layout over my ListView, this is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#dddddd"
        android:id="@+id/layout_chrono">

        <Chronometer
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:textColor="@color/orange"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/chrono" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listview_training"
        android:layout_below="@id/layout_chrono">

    </ListView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/layout_chrono"
        android:id="@+id/music_layout"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:background="#444444">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Titolo della canzone - Autore" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/prev_music" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/start_music" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/next_music" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I attach a OnClickListener on my component in that Layout, but when I click on it both listeners (the one of the background listView and the one of the component in the layout) are called.
Is there a way to call only the one of the component in foreground?
I know that I can detach the listener from the background listView when showing the foreground layout, but I'd prefer a classier way.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create your own View which in your case probably extends LinearLayout. This custom View then overrides onTouchEvent which takes MotionEvent as argument.

What this method returns depends on whether the event is consumed or not by the condition you set (e.g: whether you want to pass click, swipe, etc). If the event is not consumed then it will be passed on.